# AMP Equivalent of onchange window location URL

Tags: amp-html

The following HTML code correctly takes the user to the URL specified in the "value" of "option" tag on a standard HTML webpage:

```
<form>
<select name="URL" onchange="window.location.href=this.form.URL.options[this.form.URL.selectedIndex].value">
<option value=''>By Price Range ($)</option>
<option value='example.com/mobiles-1-20.php'>1 to 20</option>
<option value='example.com/mobiles-20-30.php'>20 to 30</option>
<option value='example.com/mobiles-30-50.php'>30 to 50</option>
</select>
</form>
```

However, the above is not compatible with AMP.

Does anyone know what is the AMP equivalent for the above form/option code?
Basically, I am looking for a dropdown form. As soon as a user selects a value from that dropdown, they should be taken to that particular URL on a AMP compatible form.

Comment: Google AMP does not support JavaScript. I believe that is not possible because AMP pages are designed to be stripped-down, basic pages.

Comment: Google AMP is "all JavaScript". The issue is using customized JavaScript where there are limitations.

Comment: You're gonna need to use https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-form/. You may be able to use an AMP event handler (have not tried to map your event to an amp-event; will leave that to you). Alternatively, you can use `amp-script` and bind the event to the target DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

Try using navigateTo() on change event in AMP here is a sample code for the same.

```
<select name="sortBy" id="sortBy" class="optionSelectSort" on="change:AMP.navigateTo(url=event.value)">
                  <option value="/link" disabled selected>Default Sort </option>
                  <option value="/link?sortBy=title-ascending" >Alphabetically, A-Z</option>
                  <option value="/link?sortBy=title-descending" >Alphabetically, Z-A</option>
                  <option value="/link?sortBy=price-ascending" >Price, low to high</option>
                  <option value="/link?sortBy=price-descending" >Price, high to low</option>
                </select>
```

here is the reference link for the same [navigationTo()](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-actions-and-events#special-targets)
and check the example [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/standard-actions.amp.html)